# "How can I modify the below program so it prints in a specific format?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, debugging

I am trying to modify the below program so it prints the string in the following format

**input**: `Fred, 4`

**output**:

```
Fred

Fred Fred

Fred Fred Fred

Fred Fred Fred Fred
```

**There are 3 mistakes in this code:**

```
def prlines(str, num):

    n in range(0,num):

    print (str (n + 1))


prlines()
```

**So I already tried the following code:**

```
name=str(input('Enter a name:'))  
num=int(input('Enter a number:'))  

 def prlines(str, num):  

    for n in range(0, num):

      print(str*(n + 1))

 print(prlines(name, num))
```

**I get this Actual Results (e.g with the Name 'Fred' and the Number '4'):**

```
Fred

FredFred

FredFredFred

FredFredFredFred

None
```

My question is How can I get the expected results to display with the following constraints:

- without None at the end
- with spaces between the strings

Comment: You can add a space to the end of your name string when you're initializing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

**Code Analysis**

```
name=str(input('Enter a name:'))  
num=int(input('Enter a number:'))  

def prlines(str, num):  

    for n in range(0, num):

        print(str*(n + 1)) # No spaces added = No spaces on the output

print(prlines(name, num)) # You are printing the output of the above function, which is None since it has no "return"
```

The `print(func())`is where you get your None from

Since you are only printing the str multiple times, you didn't include spaces (python won't know :)

**Answer**

```
name=str(input('Enter a name:'))  
num=int(input('Enter a number:'))  

def prlines(str, num):  
    for n in range(0, num):
        print((str+' ')*(n + 1))

prlines(name, num)
```

**Advice**

This code is quite rough, you would need to think about error handling when someone doesn't input an int in the second input.

Comment: Just a note: this has a trailing space at the end of each line.

Comment: This comment was very helpful! I see the Problem now with the printing at the end. Now it works perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
f'{s} ' * n + f'{s}'
```

**Code**:

```
name = input('Enter a name: ')
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

def prlines(s, num):
    for n in range(num):
        print(f'{s} ' * n + f'{s}') 

prlines(name, num)
```

**Few points**:

- Don't name variable as `str`.
- A function by default with no `return`, returns `None`, hence you have a `None` at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer worked perfectly. I'd like to understand it as well. I am a very very Beginner in programming, so why is there no "none", eventhough there is still no return for the function?

Comment: @iamichiel: When you are calling a function, you can print the returned value like `print(function())`. In this case if this function is not returning anything, python assumes the function is returning a `None`. So `None` is printed. In the code above, we don't print while the function is called.

Comment: AH NOW I saw that you did not print it at the end. So that is the reason. Thank you again and have a nice day!

Comment: Exactly. Good day!